# Jssor slider - is there a way to start the slider from a stopped state?

Tags: slider, jssor

I would like to have my page load with the slider in a stopped condition so a user can start it when he chooses to.  Is there a way of doing this?  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the api `$Play` method.
https://www.jssor.com/development/api-methods-properties-events.html